# Prevent user from executing script in input form

Tags: c#, .net, xss

I've noticed that i can inject scripts in my HTML input using that syntax :

```
'-alert("test")-'
```

I tried to fix the problem by removing all the special characters in the string i get back in C# :

```
Request.Params["s"] // i delete here all the special characters
```

However, despite that, the script keeps executing and i don't really understand why.
If anyone can put some light on this problem, thank you in advance

PS: code used to remove special characters:

```
public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str) 
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach (char c in str) {
      if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || c == '.' || c == '_') {
         sb.Append(c);
      }
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Html encode the text when you show it instead.

Comment: Your code is ok, either you have cached the version without sanitization code or you sanitize wrong string...

Comment: @Magnus, what do you mean with "when you show it" ? thx

Comment: When you render the string to your html page you should html encode it. This will avoid any script injection. Is this for webforms or mvc? If mvc which version?

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET webforms

Comment: i tried this but it still does not work : String terms = RemoveSpecialCharacters(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Request.Params["s"]));